# Where can I find learning resources for implementing a C preprocessor?

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

Much has been written over the years on implementing parsers, but the C preprocessor is not quite the same as any of the stages of a typical parser, and implementation thereof doubtless has its share of particular pitfalls to watch out for. Does anyone know of anything written on the topic of implementing a C preprocessor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a useful discussion in the document mcpp-summary at http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 7):

Hartmut Kaiser, the author of [Boost Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/wave/index.html), wrote a nice article on CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/wave_preprocessor.aspx about the Boost Wave project. You can use Boost Wave to make your own C preprocessor with custom extensions.

Answer (score 3):

I've based mine on [the gnu internals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://marc.info/?l=boost&m=118835769257658) is the clearest and most explicit guide I have found on how macro expansion works. It is written by Paul Mensonides, one of the authors of the [Boost Preprocessor library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

Macros are only one feature of the preprocessor though, so you may need to seek out other resources for guides on how to implement its other features such as file inclusion and static conditionals. However, macros are in my opinion the most complex feature of the preprocessor, and this guide should be immensely helpful in implementing them.

EDIT: I've recently stumbled upon [another guide](https://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20060626/cpp.algo.pdf) on implementing macro expansion. This one is written by
Diomidis Spinellis, a professor of software engineering at Athens University.